# Can VS Code extension register toggleable menu item?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I see the VS Code self has a lot of menu items which are toggleable. For example:
[image]

Is this capability also exposed to the extension?

Comment: The GUI API used by VSC is not all available for extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the day 1/26/2021, it seems the VS Code does not expose this in its API. Neither having plan to do it: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/103557